# Name arguments in views

Tags: views, 6

I used Name module to get the Full name of the User.I have created two views one with the all list of names and other profile info.If we click a name it will show up profile of that user.

I am passing full name as an argument in the URL to the second view (field_name: full).

I tried to add full name as argument in the second view but it does not have full name field it has been broken down into

field_name : given

field_name : family

Is there any way to get full name as an argument ??

Comment: Do you have added the field: full in the filter? Set it to hidden. And most important to reorder it right? Above your other fields?

Comment: No I haven't added the field_name: full in the filter.It does not have that type of field.